# Is there an Elixir equivalent for Clojure's (source fn-name)?

Tags: clojure, elixir

Clojure has this handy way to view a function's definition in REPL.
Is there one in Elixir REPL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a convenient way yet.

Comment: I like the 'yet.' part of your answer :) +1

Comment: @José Valim is this available yet? It'd be *super* handy!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to post this as an answer, even though it's not the same as "source". In IEX, you can type `h function_name` to see the documentation for `function_name`. It's basically Clojure REPL's `doc` feature. So far, in Elixir, this is good enough for most cases where I want `source`.